# Multiple Inheritance from interfaces (abstract classes)

Tags: c++

So I have two abstract classes ; one defined like this :

```
class Bindable
{
    virtual void Bind() const = 0;
    virtual void UnBind() const = 0;
};
```

and another defined as the following :

```
class Disposable
{
    virtual void Dispose() = 0;
}
```

and I make the `Component` class inherit from their virtual methods like this :

```
class Component : public virtual Bindable, public virtual Disposable
{
    //method implementations...
    void Bind() const;
    void UnBind() const;
    void Dispose();
}
```

So :  Am I doing it right ? Do I need to inherit from those two abstract classes virtually ? Or Did I miss something ? (I haven't faced a multiple inheritance situation yet, so I'm not really used to it...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to inherit virtually here. Virtual inheritance is only needed when there is diamond inheritance (See C++ FAQ [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond)). In this case you can simply inherit normally without worrying about having multiple instances of either `Bindable` or `Disposable` in the inheritance hierarchy.

Another thing, `Bindable` and `Disposable` should probably have virtual destructors so that they are destroyed properly if the class is destroyed through either of the interfaces. So you should add this to `Disposable`

```
virtual ~Disposable() { }
```

and this to `Bindable`

```
virtual ~Bindable() { }
```

Comment: Thanks :) Bindable, and Disposable are just inhereted from the component class to inform the user of the library to dispose and bind those objects: they contain no more then those two methods! The user Is not supposed to Access them, and they have no attribs to destroy!

Answer (score 3):

As written, your example doesn't require virtual inheritance. But in cases where it's required, the virtual inheritance should not be in the class multiply inheriting from two classes anyway.

Where it might be necessary to use virtual inheritance is not in your
Component class, but in your Bindable and Disposable classes, if  there is any possibility of ambiguity between them.

One example would be if Bindable and Disposable both, in turn, inherited from the same pure virtual base class:

```
class Parent
{
  private:
      int someData=0;
  public:
      virtual int someMethod() const = 0;

}
```

Without virtual inheritance, your Component class would have an ambiguity. It would inherit from two  now-concrete classes, which both in turn inherit from an abstract base class. Which version of someData and someMethod would Component get? It would get both because of non-virtual inheritance.

In that case, you would want  Bindable and Disposable to both inherit virtually from Parent.

```
class Bindable: public virtual Parent
{
    virtual void Bind() ;
    virtual void UnBind();
};

class Disposable public virtual Parent
{
    virtual void Dispose();
};
```

You would then have only one copy of Parent in Component, solving the ambiguity.

I agree with @Phantom about the virtual destructors too.

Comment: No need for destructor : no data to destroy !!!!! I'll add them though, just in case...